# What is the meaning/history of the echo word? [Etymology]

Tags: echo, theory, history

Can anyone explain the meaning of the *"echo"* word?

I know it is used commonly for printing information as output but I couldn't find any clear explanation for it.

It's because the command *echoes* the passed parameters as output?

Answer (score 0):

This might help [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Echo_(command))

> echo began within Multics, and became part of Version 2 Unix. echo -n
>   in Version 7 replaced prompt, (which behaved like echo but without
>   terminating its output with a line delimiter).[3]
>
> On PWB/UNIX and later Unix System III, echo started expanding C escape
>   sequences such as \n with the notable difference that octal escape
>   sequences were expressed as \0ooo instead of \ooo in C

Answer (score 0):

From [this answer](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/12646/why-is-the-echo-command-called-echo) in stackexchange

> Imagine yourself standing in a rift with a great echo. Whatever you shout comes back to you. And much like the echo on a lake, it is someone else 'speaking' here: the machine, not you. Type it at the command line and it, well, commands the machine to 'echo' what you 'said'.